# Unable to set LS_COLORS in bash using script

Tags: bash, shell-script, colors, exec, settings

I am trying to set the LS_COLORS environment variable using a launcher script. However this variable is not being set.

#### Steps

1. Downloaded [LS_COLORS](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS) to ~/.dircolors
2. Added **TERM=xterm-newTerminalEmulator** where all the other **TERM** variables were defined in .dircolors
3. Created a launcher script in ~/bin/ls
4. Populated this launcher script with the shebang, `eval` to pass the strings in bracket as a command to the shell and `exec` to replace all processes with just the `ls` process:

   `#!/bin/sh
   eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)
   exec /bin/ls "$@"`
5. Made the `~/bin/ls` file executable.

The man page for dir_colors says

> Usually,
>          the file used here is /etc/DIR_COLORS and can be overridden by a
>          .dir_colors file in one's home directory.

Would this be why its not working, considering only the system wide /etc/DIR_COLORS script is being used?

#### Additionally

I also have an alias for `ls` set as **alias ls = "ls --color"** and `echo $LS_COLORS` shows nothing.

*System specifications are: fedora28 and bash*

#### UPDATE

I got this working, but I am not satisfied with the colors. The defaults are more intuitive, not only this but **LS_COLORS** does not differentiate between executables and symlinks which is a deal breaker.

Comment: likely your `TERM` variable isn't **`xterm-newTerminalEmulator`** (and if it is, likely it's longer than the allowed length for the **`ls`** program).

Comment: that was an example and not the real value of the __TERM__ variable. The real value is much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation's vague, but setting the environment variable isn't enough: you need the `--color` option.  Without an option value, that corresponds to `--color=always` (most people expect `--color=auto`, which suppresses the color in a pipe).

You can see how the `--color` option is treated in the [source-code for ls](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c), in particular the variable [`print_with_color`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L559) and its interaction with [`LS_COLORS`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L2514).

For what it's worth, the `eval` command is needed to evaluate the `export` command returned by `dircolors`, and that environment variable is preserved across the `exec`.  Your example (with the added `--color` option) worked for me with bash and dash.

Comment: Are you saying that if I want LS_COLORS to work then I have to set the `--color` option to auto? I set an alia for `--color` exactly for the reason you mentioned - to allow colors when piped to `less`.

Comment: I already set the `--color` option in an alias as shown above. Did I mention that __/bin__ is a symlink and not a directory? Could this be the problem?

Comment: Whether `/bin` is a symlink or not doesn't matter.  Other `ls` is aliased to have the `--color` option; you'd notice this difference in scripts which don't inherit aliases from the parent (only environment variables would be inherited).

Answer (score 0):

You're running dircolors in a subshell, so the changes only apply within the subshell.

The subshell is $( ... )

Try this instead...

```
alias ls="dircolors -b ~/.dircolors && ls"
```

Comment: I am not sure how using the command substitution runs dircolors in a subshell. As far as I know that is what the command `bash` is for. I rather not set an alias for this because I also have the `exec /bin/ls` command. A launcher script is the right way to do it but something seems to be missing.

Comment: @mywrath everything within the parenthesis of the command substitution is run under a subshell, which is a copy of the parent environment. So the output is used for the value of the "variable" but no other side effects escape